# Translating basic Actionscript game code into Java?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3

I have been trying to translate [this tutorial into Java code](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-unlockable-achievements-for-your-game-a-simple-approach--gamedev-6012), as I want to make a simple game with level/achievements in android (and haven't found as thorough/basic examples in java online, if you have one please share)

Please help me understand:
How can I link different file of classes together? in the example they don't seem to refer to each other? Basically how can I pass on the properties and settings from the tasks/games to these functions which are elsewhere in the code? do I just refer to the class several times throughout the code?

For example I am stuck in this part, could use help in understanding how this works in java code? (examples are most appreciated)

```
> private var mProps :Object; // dictionary of properties
  private var mAchievements :Object; // dictionary of achievements

  public function Achieve() {
    mProps = { };
    mAchievements = { };
  }

public function defineProperty(theName :String, theInitialValue :int, theaActivationMode :String, theValue :int) :void {
  mProps[theName] = new Property(theName, theInitialValue, theaActivationMode, theValue);
}

public function defineAchievement(theName :String, theRelatedProps :Array) :void {
  mAchievements[theName] = new Achievement(theName, theRelatedProps);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that each class must go to its own file.

```
public class Property {
      private String mName;
      private int mValue;
      private String mActivation;
      private int mActivationValue;
      private int mInitialValue;

      public Property(String theName, int theInitialValue, String theActivation, int theActivationValue) {
        mName = theName;
        mActivation = theActivation;
        mActivationValue = theActivationValue;
        mInitialValue = theInitialValue;
      }

      public int getValue() {
          return mValue;
      }

      public void setValue(int n) {
          mValue = n;
      }

      public boolean isActive() {
          boolean aRet = false;
          switch(mActivation) {
              case Achieve.ACTIVE_IF_GREATER_THAN: aRet = mValue > mActivationValue; break;
              case Achieve.ACTIVE_IF_LESS_THAN: aRet = mValue < mActivationValue; break;
              case Achieve.ACTIVE_IF_EQUALS_TO: aRet = mValue == mActivationValue; break;
          }

          return aRet;
      }

      public String getActivation() {
          return mActivation;
      }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Achievement {
  private String mName; // achievement name
  private ArrayList<String> mProps; // array of related properties
  private boolean mUnlocked; // achievement is unlocked or not

  public Achievement(String theId, ArrayList<String> theRelatedProps) {
    mName = theId;
    mProps = theRelatedProps;
    mUnlocked = false;
  }

  public boolean isUnlocked() {
      return mUnlocked;
  }

  public void setUnlocked(boolean b) {
      mUnlocked = b;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getProps() {
      return mProps;
  }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Achieve {
  // activation rules
  public static final String ACTIVE_IF_GREATER_THAN = ">";
  public static final String ACTIVE_IF_LESS_THAN = "<";
  public static final String ACTIVE_IF_EQUALS_TO = "==";

  private HashMap<String,Property> mProps; // dictionary of properties
  private HashMap<String,Achievement> mAchievements; // dictionary of achievements

  public Achieve() {
      mProps = new HashMap<String,Property>();
      mAchievements = new HashMap<String,Achievement>();
  }

  public void defineProperty(String theName, int theInitialValue, String theaActivationMode, int theValue) {
      mProps.put(theName, new Property(theName, theInitialValue, theaActivationMode, theValue));
  }

  public void defineAchievement(String theName, ArrayList<String> theRelatedProps) {
      mAchievements.put(theName, new Achievement(theName, theRelatedProps));
  }

  public int getValue(String theProp) {
      Property p = mProps.get(theProp);
      if (p != null) return p.getValue();
      return 0;
  }

  public void setValue(String theProp, int theValue) {
      Property p = mProps.get(theProp);
      if (p == null) return;
       switch(p.getActivation()) {
         case Achieve.ACTIVE_IF_GREATER_THAN:
             theValue = theValue > p.getValue() ? theValue : p.getValue();
             break;
         case Achieve.ACTIVE_IF_LESS_THAN:
             theValue = theValue < p.getValue() ? theValue : p.getValue();
             break;
      }

      p.setValue(theValue);
  }

  public void addValue(ArrayList<String> theProps, int theValue) {
      for (int i = 0; i < theProps.size(); i++) {
        String aPropName = theProps.get(i);
        setValue(aPropName, getValue(aPropName) + theValue);
      }
  }

  public ArrayList<Achievement> checkAchievements() {
      ArrayList<Achievement> aRet = new ArrayList<Achievement>();
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Achievement>> it = mAchievements.entrySet().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Achievement> pair = it.next();
        Achievement aAchievement = pair.getValue();
        if (!aAchievement.isUnlocked()) {
          int aActiveProps = 0;
          ArrayList<String> props = aAchievement.getProps();
          for (int p = 0; p < props.size(); p++) {
            Property aProp= mProps.get(props.get(p));
            if (aProp.isActive()) {
              aActiveProps++;
            }
          }

          if (aActiveProps == props.size()) {
            aAchievement.setUnlocked(true);
            aRet.add(aAchievement);
          }
        }
      }
      return aRet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing this gives me a bunch of errors, I had to take out the "function" from "public function Acheive()". 

The second example also gives me a bunch of errors namely "Multiple markers at this line
 - Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be 
  parameterized
 - Cannot instantiate the type Property
 - Property is a raw type. References to generic type Property<T,V> should be parameterized"

It's also unclear to me how this would fit in an array as one of the properties (as for function defineAcheivement)

Comment: Well you see Java is not a very simple language so it is highly desirable that you know at least some basics first. You cannot just copy and paste examples because even if they compile, they might work not as expected. Right now there seems to be no other answer except writing and testing the fully working code for you, for which I don't have time, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Ok thank you , I appreciate your help so far. It's the "Cannot instantiate the type Property" that is throwing me off really in the example, assuming this is the right method to use.

Comment: Ok, I just needed to reinstall Eclipse so I tested it with this code. I think I adapted pretty much all, the rest is up to you. I'm going to update the answer now.

Comment: Wow thank you ! you're awesome. Most of it works without errors, although the Achieve class is still giving me errors with instantiating a "new Property", with getValue() and isActive() showing "undefined for the type Property"  but I'm trying to figure that out myself, thank you!

Comment: Most probably you have some other Property class elsewhere. Try replacing this Property name with something different.